# "Choose burger" or "Choose the burger" or "Choose a burger". Picking the right article

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, phrases

Which one is correct? Specifically, the context is a restaurant menu with multiple choices available when the main item/dish is picked. Should articles be used generally when listing choices?

Could you open up the comments again? I just need to screenshot the comments.